# Converting from Ideal Basis to Binary Quadratic Form

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I understand there is a correspondence between binary quadratic forms and ideals in quadratic number fields. I am working in quadratic number fields and I am working with ideals of the form 
$$I = (A, \frac{B+C\sqrt{D}}{2E}) $$
and only in cases where $E\mid B$ and $E\mid C$. When I convert this to a binary quadratic form, the discriminant of the form ends up being $(\frac{C}{E})^2D$ which makes sense, but its not equal to $D$ as I would want. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I am using to convert: [Ideal to BQF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnXDY.png)

Comment: what book are you using? Note that there is now a beginning book called Quadratic Number Theory by Lehman, he does ideals and quadratic forms side by side, https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-52/

Comment: Thanks! I edited the post with the source I am using

Comment: right. This is in the format of a modern published book, what book is that?

Comment: You need to write the ideal using a ${\mathbb Z}$-basis. Your representation in the form $(\alpha, \beta)$ does not even allow to determine the norm of the ideal, which you need for computing the associated quadratic form.

Comment: From context I know the norm is equal to A

Comment: @mathymathymathymate  if you reply to someone else's comment you should begin with an @ sign and the beginning of that username. After you have typed a few letters such as fra , the system should display that entire username so you can click on it. If you do that, the user (franz) gets a notification of your message next time he looks at the site, a red flag at the top of the page. As matters stand, there is no reason to think that Franz will ever be aware of your comment. Since this is your question, you automatically are notified.